# Как упростить программу?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, математика, простые-числа, факторизация

Написал на C++ программу которая при вводе числа (от 0 до 10<sup>10</sup>), выводит 1, если это число простое, и 0, если оно составное. Функцию `IsPrime` реализовать надо было обязательно.

Программа работает, но проблема в том, что в 2 из 9 тестов нарушает предел времени 1 секунду. Как упростить программу, чтобы она не нарушала предел времени?

Код прилагаю:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
bool IsPrime(long long a)
{
    bool z=1;
    int i;
    bool isPrimess = true;
    i=2;
    while(i <= a / 2)
    {
        if(a % i == 0)
        {
          isPrimess = false;
          break;
        }
       i++;
    }
    if (!isPrimess){z=0;
                    return z;}
}
int main()
{
    long long int a;
    cin>>a;
    if(a==0 || a==1)
    {
        cout<<"0"<<endl;
    }
    else{
    cout<<IsPrime(a)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В функции isPrime,  если  isPrimess = true, то даже нет условия выхода из функции.

Comment: Похоже это хотели сделать bool IsPrime(long long a)
{
    int i;
    i=2;
    while(i <= a / 2)
    {
        if(a % i == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}

Comment: @JaponDemon то же самое по времени, на тех же тестах падает

Comment: И кстати, по-русски - это простое число, а не первичное...

Comment: @Harry не знал, исправлюсь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такой тупой вариант должен вложиться в нужное время:

```
bool IsPrime(int num)
{
    if (num < 2) return false;
    if (num == 2) return true;
    if (num%2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i*i <= num; i+=2)
    {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

А вообще - здесь столько раз разбиралась эта и похожие задачи, что не найти просто сложно... Например , вот по такому [запросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[c%2B%2B]%20%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Answer (score 2):

Простые модификации - ограничить диапазон проверки корнем из числа и проверять только делители вида `6*k-1` и `6*k-1` (конечно, помимо 2 и 3).

Более эффективные алгоритмы потребуют уже применения более серьезной математики

И неужели тест на время должна проходить программа с проверкой простоты одного числа?

Answer (score 1):

Если уж совсем просто, то реализовывать стоит примерно так:

```
bool isPrime (unsigned int x) {
    if (x < 2) { return false; }
    for (unsigned i = 2; i * i <= x; i++) {
        if ((x % i) == 0) { return false; }
    }
    return true;
}
```